# How to change MediatR publish strategy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mediatr

how is it possible to configure another publishing strategy when using MediatR? basically i need to configure it to use publishingStrategy.ParallelNoWait. any help would be appreciated since im not able to find any documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See following github discussion for an answer
https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/discussions/736